# Run Python Script from PHP Docker

Tags: php, python, shell, docker, command-line

I am running a Docker. Here is my docker file.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my wget gnupg
RUN apt-key adv \
        --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
        --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libssl-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y libmariadbclient-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv mcrypt mysqli pdo_mysql mysql zip mbstring
RUN pecl install mongo
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer
RUN sed -i 's/^ServerSignature/#ServerSignature/g' /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf; \
    sed -i 's/^ServerTokens/#ServerTokens/g' /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf; \
    echo "ServerSignature Off" >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf; \
    echo "ServerTokens Prod" >> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf; \
    a2enmod ssl; \
    a2enmod headers; \
    echo "SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install image_match
RUN pip3 install opencv-python
RUN pip3 install pytube
RUN pip3 install ez_setup
RUN pip3 install moviepy
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install ffmpeg-python
RUN apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6
RUN apt-get install -y libxrender-dev
RUN apt-get update
COPY config/mongo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

ENV VERSION 8
ENV UPDATE 91
ENV BUILD 14
```

In one my PHP Page, I want to Run a python script. for e.g.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python integrateFinal.py');
$joutput = shell_exec($command);
$output=json_decode($joutput);
```

The python script works fine with the command line as 'docker-compose exec web python3 integrateFinal.py'. It works and gives the output but when I run it from PHP page mentioned above It gives me error as permission denied.

So How should I run this PYTHON script?

Comment: Make sure the file has permission first. it should be able to execute under any privilege

Comment: How to Do that? I am running Linux containers on my Windows System.

Comment: In one of your `RUN` commands, you can execute a `chmod` against the php script, python script, or both, depending on which is having the errors thrown against it. Your python script needs to have read access at least in order to run